# Asp.net Web api 2 Facebook login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to authenticate a user via Facebook for my web api. I am able to authenticate the user when I specify the returnurl parameter to the base of the web site.

My site layout is the following in my test environment:

> http://subdomain.main.com/api/ - This is the api location
>
> http://subdomain.main.com/web/ - This is the client website location

I get the list of providers via the api and it returns the following JSON

```
[{"Name":"Facebook","Url":"/api/api/Account/ExternalLogin?
provider=Facebook&response_type=token&
client_id=self&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsubdomain.main.com%2F&state=mScYbSFDVHMMxVH8kaNWmDUNhqo2s4RFbG9SaBXt_jM1","State":"mScYbSFDVHMMxVH8kaNWmDUNhqo2s4RFbG9SaBXt_jM1"}]
```

I then redirect the user to the url provided by the API. This opens Facebook and asks the user to allow my app.

So its all working when I use the base url, but when I change the returnurl to the following:

> https://subdomain.main.com/api/api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=https://subdomain.main.com**/web/**&generateState=true

The api returns a url as normal, but when I try to redirect the user to the url provided it just returns:

> error: invalid_request

How can I get the API to redirect to my website so that I can catch the oauth token?

Answer (score 6):

You need to edit the ValidateClientRedirectUri method to include your custom return uri. The default template code only permits the root of your website as a valid return uri.

The example below is a quick hack till you decide on the exact return uri.

```
public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
    {
        if (context.ClientId == _publicClientId)
        {
            Uri expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, "/");

            if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == context.RedirectUri)
            {
                context.Validated();
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```

to

```
public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
    {
        if (context.ClientId == _publicClientId)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```